# Force slim DVD and laptop HD on desktop motherboard to proper master/slave setting

Tags: hard-drive, bios, optical-drive, pata

I'm trying to add a slim DVD to my file server. The motherboard is a JetWay JNC81-LF, but I doubt the specific model is relevant, just that it's a desktop Mini-ITX board. I'm using a [Chenbro ES34069](http://usa.chenbro.com/corporatesite/products_detail.php?sku=79) case, which requires both a slim optical drive and a laptop hard drive due to space constraints.

The hard drive is a 40GB Seagate Momentus 5200.2. I am using an adapter [like this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000067RRQ) to connect it to the system:

The DVD drive I'm trying to add is a [TS-L532B](https://support.dell.com/support/edocs/storage/P94660/en/specs.htm). I am using [this adapter](http://www.bixnet.com/notslimcdtod.html) to connect it to the system.

Due to the space issues I mentioned earlier, I am using the 80-pin IDE cable "backwards". That is, the blue end, which normally goes attached to the motherboard, is attached to the hard drive. The grey connector, normally slave, goes to the DVD drive and the black connector, normally master goes to the motherboard.

This is what I have tried

- Hard drive by itself, no jumpers: HD gets detected as master.
- DVD by itself: DVD gets detected as slave.
- HD with no jumper set, DVD connected: HD gets detected as master, DVD shows up as slave, but the name is corrupted: "T≈S⌡cδr⌡ δVδ+Ñ-⌡", and is shown as a 2300MB hard drive.
- HD with jumper set to cable select: Same result as when no jumper is set.
- HD with jumper set to slave, DVD connected: Neither HD nor DVD are detected.

While researching this problem I've learned that some slim drives just won't work as anything but masters. Since I'm running Linux this actually doesn't matter to me, the boot drive can be the slave with no problem.

Does anybody have any ideas about how I can have my hard and DVD drives coexists in this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the DVD drive is obviously set to "cable select" since it has no jumpers I presume. You will have these issues when you try to connect the cable backwards. If cannot connect this cable the right way, you should consider making a custom IDE cable to fit you need.

Comment: Well, I'll be. It's embarrassing that I didn't think to debug the position of the cable first, assuming that "bits are bits". I don't have the skills to make a custom IDE cable, so I just ordered a longer one and I'll tie the excess. Thanks.